# python : Get Active Sheet in xlrd? and help for reading and validating excel file in Python

Tags: python, xlrd, openpyxl, xlwt, xlutils

2 Questions to ask:

**Ques 1:**
I just started studying about [xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html) for reading excel file in python.
I was wondering if there is a method in xlsrd --> similar to `get_active_sheet()` in [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/) or any other way to get the Active sheet ?

`get_active_sheet()` works this in `openpyxl`

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

active_sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
```

output : Worksheet "Sheet1"

I had found methods in `xlrd` for retrieving the names of sheets, but none of them could tell me the active sheet.

**Ques 2:**

Is `xlrd` the best packaage in python for reading excel files? I also came across [this](http://www.python-excel.org/) which had info about other python packages(`xlsxwriter``xlwt``xlutils`) for reading and writing excel files.

Which of the above all will be best for making an App which reads an Excel File and applies different validations to to different columns

For eg: Column with Header 'ID' should have unique values and A column with Header 'Country' should have valid Countries.

Answer (score 5):

The "active sheet" here seems you're referring to the last sheet selected when the workbook was saved/closed. You can get this sheet via [the `sheet_visible` value](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/e1930e40c02694ef5136e7ace793ccad9a581bd9/xlrd/sheet.py#L33-L40).

```
import xlrd
xl = xlrd.open_workbook("example.xls")
for sht in xl.sheets():
    # sht.sheet_visible value of 1 is "active sheet"
    print(sht.name, sht.sheet_selected, sht.sheet_visible)
```

Usually only one sheet is selected at a time, so it may look like `sheet_visible` and `sheet_selected` are the same, but multiple sheets can be selected at a time (ctrl+click multiple sheet tabs, for example).

Another reason this may seem confusing is because Excel uses "visible" in terms of hidden/visible sheets. In xlrd, this is instead sheet.visibility (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583134/4258124)

Comment: Anyways to get the active cell after getting the active sheet using the way you mentioned?

Comment: @Eswar not sure, but I don't think so. Even if you could, I think *valid* use cases would be extremely slim to none. If you do really need, you could use something like win32com to open Excel and interact with it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to `Stack Overflow`.

I have been working with `Excel` files in `Python` for a while now, so I could help you with your question, I think.

`openpyxl` and `xlrd` solve different problems, one is for `xlsx` files (Excel 2007+), where the other one is for `xls` files (Excel 1997-2003), respectively.

`Xenon` said in his answer that `Excel` doesn't recognize the concept of an `active` sheet, which is not totally true. If you open an `Excel` document, go to some other sheet (that isn't the first one) and save and close the document, the next time you open it, `Excel` will open the document on the last sheet you were on.

However, `xlrd` does not support this kind of workflow, i.e. asking for the `active` sheet. If you know the sheet name, then you could use the method `sheet_by_name`, or if you know the sheet index, you could use the method `sheet_by_index`.

I don't know if the `xlrd` is the best package around, but it is pretty solid, and I have had nary a problem using it.

The example given could be solved by first iterating through the first row and keeping a dictionary of which column a header is. Then storing all the values in the ID column in a list and comparing the length of that list with the length of a set created from that list, i.e. `len(values) == len(set(values))`. Following that, you could iterate through the column with header of Country and check each value if it is in a dictionary you previously made with all the valid counties.

I hope this answer suits your needs.

Summary: Stick with `xlrd` because is mature enough.

Comment: this is incorrect, see my answer - the OP's desired functionality has existed in xlrd for >10 years

Comment: Actually , I doubt the version range you mentioned. I have some excel files created with Excel 2007, that openpyxl could not read many cell values, and gave nontype value. I tried with xlrd , and it read smoothly

Comment: I am not sure if I could ask a new question , since there are so many questions asked about this around

Comment: cause it seems that even in higher versions of Excel, still the xlrd works better

Comment: I even save the file with Excel 2016 but no change

Answer (score 1):

You can see all worksheets in a given workbook with the `sheet_names()` function. Excel has no concept of an "active sheet", but if my assumption that you are referring to the first sheet is correct, you can get the first element of `sheet_names()` to get the "active sheet."

With regards to your second question, it's not easy to say that a package is better than another package objectively. However, `xlrd` is widely used, and the most popular Python library for what it does.

I would recommend sticking with it.

Comment: Thanku for your answer, by active sheet in excel I meant the sheet which opens as a default sheet when we open the Excel File. There is a concept of Active sheet ( [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841181.aspx) ) in Excel.

Comment: this is incorrect, see my answer - the OP's desired functionality has existed in xlrd for >10 years

Comment: @NikT what's OP's desired functionality? Can you please explain?