# How to read only visible sheets from Excel using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to get some random Excel sheets where I want to **read only visible sheets** from those files.

Consider one file at a time, let's say I have `Mapping_Doc.xls` which contains 2-visible sheets and 2-hidden sheets.

As the sheets are less here, I can parse them with names like this:

Code :

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('D:\\ExcelRead\\Mapping_Doc.xls')
print xls.sheet_names
df1 = xls.parse('Sheet1') #visible sheet
df2 = xls.parse('Sheet2') #visible sheet
```

Output:

```
[u'sheet1',u'sheet2',u'sheet3',u'sheet4']
```

How can I get only the visible sheets?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with only Pandas, you might need other libraries.

Comment: @moritzg Any Specific libraries?

Comment: I think [OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.writer.workbook.html?highlight=visible#openpyxl.writer.workbook.get_active_sheet) does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas uses the `xlrd` library internally (have a look at the [excel.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel.py) source code if you're interested).

You can determine the visibility status by accessing each sheet's `visibility` attribute. According to the comments in the [xlrd source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/sheet.py), these are the possible values:

- 0 = visible
- 1 = hidden (can be unhidden by user -- Format -> Sheet -> Unhide)
- 2 = "very hidden" (can be unhidden only by VBA macro).

Here's an example that reads an Excel file with 2 worksheets, the first one visible and the second one hidden:

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')

sheets = xls.book.sheets()

for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet.name, sheet.visibility)
```

Output:

```
Sheet1 0
Sheet2 1
```

Comment: It doesn't support '.xlsb' file . Is there any other options uing pandas?

Comment: error message: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'sheets'

Answer (score 3):

Update for pandas 1.2.3

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile(filename)

sheets = xls.book.worksheets

for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet.title, sheet.sheet_state)
```

Comment: error message: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'sheet_state'

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas 1.3.5, the response is different for the different engines:

- Excel ≤2003 files are parsed with the `xlrd` engine.
- Excel > 2003 files are parsed with the `openpyxl` engine.

This code works with both:

```
import pandas as pd
file = r'D:\path\to\File_to_Parse.xls'
excel = pd.ExcelFile(file)
if excel.engine == 'openpyxl':
    sheets = excel.book.worksheets
    for sheet in sheets:
        print(sheet.title, sheet.sheet_state) # .sheet_state returns a string
elif excel.engine == 'xlrd':
    sheets = excel.book.sheets()
    for sheet in sheets:
        print(sheet.name, sheet.visibility) # .visibility returns an integer: visible == 0, hidden > 0
else:
    print (f'{file} encoded with {excel.engine} engine. Unknown parsing.')
```

Comment: sheet_state does not exist on the new 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' objects, and I can't find a way to force openpyxl to not lazy-load the spreadsheets through pandas' ExcelFile constructor

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ, helped me too. I want to add few points.

For macro files (.xlsm), the visibility is unpredictable. May be because VBA code is behind the visibility setting. Even if a sheet is visible when the file is opened in Excel application, the visibility is not always 0 when read by xlrd.

Check the screenshots below:

This is what I see in Excel.

[image]

Visibility values fetched using xlrd

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of R&D on Pandas, but couldn't find any solution. An alternate way is to use the `xlrd` library.

You need to install version `1.2.0` to get the support for `xlsx` excel format.

```
pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

Read the excel and loop through the sheets. Inside the loop, you will get the sheet name and using the sheet name use the `sheet_by_name` method to get the sheet and on top of it use the `visibility` to find out if the sheet is visible or not.

```
import xlrd as xl
workbook = xl.open_workbook('File.xlsx')        
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    isVisible = True if workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet.name).visibility == 0 else False
    if(isVisible == True):
        print(str(isVisible) + " : " + sheet.name)
    else:
        print(str(isVisible) + " : " + sheet.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

xls = pd.ExcelFile('Test.xlsx')
sheets =xls.book.sheets()

for sheet in sheets:
    sheetnames = (sheet.name) + '-'+ str(sheet.visibility)
    if re.search(r'.*\-[0]',sheetnames):
        targetsheet = sheetnames
        targetsheet = re.search(r'(.*)(\-[0])',targetsheet)
        targetsheet = targetsheet.group(1)
        print(targetsheet)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).